# Warning: Illegal string offset 'todo' | PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Am trying to do a to-do list using PHP

but am getting this error Warning: Illegal string offset 'todo'

```
$userhastodo = "";

$toDo_Query = "SELECT * FROM `todo` WHERE `for`='".$_SESSION['id']."'";

$toDo_run_query =  mysqli_query($link , $toDo_Query);

$toDo_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($toDo_run_query);


if($toDo_num_rows >= 1){
    $toDo_get_info = mysqli_fetch_array($toDo_run_query);

    $toDo_info = $toDo_get_info;

    foreach($toDo_info as $info){
        echo $info['todo'];

    }
}
else{
    $userhastodo = "You have no lists here :( !";
}
```

that is in the top of my todo.php page

in the html part

```
        <?php if(empty($toDo_get_info)):?>
            <div class="empty">
                <i class="fa fa-meh-o fa-5x"></i>
                <h3>Strange, no lists found!</h3>
            </div>

            <?php else: ?>
                <ul class="list">
                <?php foreach($toDo_info as $info_in_toDo):?>
                    <li><span><?php echo $info_in_toDo['todo']?></span></li>
                <?php endforeach;?>
                </ul>
        <?php endif;?>
```

how can i fix this ? it keeps warning me => Warning: Illegal string offset 'todo'

todo exists in my mysql database holding the data of a to-do activity

Comment: did ur database table  `todo` have a field named 'todo'? try var_dump($info); to get more info about ur array $info

Comment: todo is your table name or your  column name inside table?

Comment: my column name inside a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at this section:

```
$toDo_get_info = mysqli_fetch_array($toDo_run_query);

$toDo_info = $toDo_get_info;

foreach($toDo_info as $info){
    echo $info['todo'];
}
```

You see that you get one row from your result set, so `$toDo_info` is a one-dimensional array containing one complete row.

You loop over that row with your `foreach` so you will get all values from that row and these are strings, not arrays.

You only need:

```
echo $toDo_get_info['todo'];
```

**Edit:** To get all rows and echo all items, you need to fetch all rows:

```
while ($toDo_get_info = mysqli_fetch_array($toDo_run_query))
{
    // add your html to add list items here as well
    echo $toDo_get_info['todo'];
}
```

Comment: i want to get all todo columns in the table when i loop i don't want to get one element how can i do that ?

Comment: thank you, but is there a way using foreach ? i was following phpacdemy series on how to do  to-do list but he used PDO with foreach

Comment: @SR11 Not directly, but in PDO you can use `fetchAll()` to get all rows in one go in one multi-dimensional array. And you can loop over that array using a `foreach`, so indirectly, yes. In mysqli you can do the same using `mysqli_fetch_all()`. The key is getting all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this

```
foreach($toDo_info as $key => $info){
    echo $info;
}
```

Better yet see @jeroen's answer...

Comment: it works but i want to loop thro all the todo columns in my table and print them

this solution will print the first row in a loop